# Do we have a tool that can track file level changes at a user level for a directory?

Tags: tracker

Do we have a tool that can track file level changes at a user level for a directory?

To further add,

My requirement is this -

This is the directory i would like to track **/var/lib/docker/volumes/shared/_data** -

Any changes to any files inside this folder should be tracked & logged. At some point of time, i would like to see who changed which file inside this. Will your code help achieve this?

How easy it is to view the expected output(user who changed/file that was changed/what was changed)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes -

> **inotifywait** - wait for changes to files using inotify

Example:

```bsh
while inotifywait -e modify /var/log/my_log; do
  if tail -n1 /var/log/my_log | grep error; then
    write_email_to_support
  fi
done
```

---

For your specific use case you can use `-m` (monitor) or `-d` (daemon, same as monitor, but run in background) and output (`-o`) to some log file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
inotifywait -e create,modify -m /var/lib/docker/volumes/shared/_data -o /var/log/shared_data_log
```

- Add `-r` to make `inotfiywait` watch changes recursively
- You can use `--format ...` to specify an output format.
- It is **not** possible to see who create or changed a file. That is a limitation of the file system.

See `man inotifywait` for more options.

Comment: Who created/Edited a file is an important thing that i am looking for in this requirement. Do you recommend any other UI based tools? This code that you have shared works great. Just tested it out. CREATE/MODIFY it displays great.

Comment: It is simply not possible to know created / modified a file. You can know the owner, but that does not mean anything.